# trouble on creating wiki account

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to create account or login to gazebo wiki page?
I had following error when I tried to login using Google account

```
400. That’s an error.

OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain: http://wiki.gazebosim.org

Learn more
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7770/trouble-on-creating-wiki-account/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/305/kei-okada/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-12-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The gazebo wiki is now hosted on bitbucket:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/wiki

It should be accessible with a bitbucket account.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2015-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0